# How to get data in chunk for e.g 5000 every time with different request call from db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one table with more than 13000 records. I want to get that records in one of the dropdown list in chunk for eg.  5000 every time with different request call from db through API in .Net MVC. I am using entityframework with default connection string and Oracle DB.

I tried the below code to add this in controller, but still it is giving timeout error.
As service itself is throwing timeout error.  I dont't want to increase the timeout in web.config.

```cs
var result = this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

The error getting when tried to call the data in one request:
[image: The error getting when tried to call the data in one request]

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE; it is not a database. Oracle is probably your database but SQL Developer can connect to other databases so that is not certain.

Comment: Please do not include images instead of text. Copy-paste the text of the error message into the question.